# Select item from JPanel and JTable

Tags: java, swing

I m building a Java swing application. Now I have a method to load some Object into my table. I need to show at the user a list of all Articles in database. The articles can be more thant 1000. So I want to show at the user a Table with all articles, the user can select one of this and the method should to return the selected article at the principal method.
So I have this code:

this is the principal method and I need to show a list of all articoles at the user when I call "controllaQuantita" method.

```
public Carico leggiOrdineDaFile_Moderna(Fornitore f,String file,List<Articoli> listaArticoliDett){
        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String strLine;
            Carico ordine = new Carico();
            List<DettOrdini> listaArticoli = new ArrayList<DettOrdini>();
            int cont=0;
            //Read File Line By Line
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                //SPLITTO LA STRINGA CON IL TERMINATORE DI RIGA CHE E' 005614
                String stringaContenitore = strLine;
                String codiceABarre = strLine.substring(93,113);
                Articoli articolo = modelManager.getArticoliManager().estraiArticolo(codiceABarre,true,null,false);
                if(articolo !=null){
                   //todo     
                }else{
                    int risposta = VisualMessageOrdini.getInserimentoNuovoArticolo(nomeArticolo,codiceABarre);
                    if(risposta == 0){
                       //todo
                    }
                    }else{
                        controllaQuantita(false, listaArticoliDett);
                    }
                }
                //System.out.println (strLine);
                cont++;
            }
            //Close the input stream
            br.close();
            ordine.setDettOrdini(listaArticoli);
            ordine.setFornitore(f);
            return ordine;
        }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
            log.logStackTrace(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

this is the method controllaQuantita:

```
public void controllaQuantita(boolean isTagliaColore, List<Articoli> artInMagazzino){
        //List<Articoli> articoliMancanti =listaArticoli = modelManager.getArticoliManager().estraiArticoli(false,true,false,false,false,
        //      null,isTagliaColore,null,null,false,null,null,false);
        PanelArticoliPerOrdine panelArtM = new PanelArticoliPerOrdine(artInMagazzino);
        panelArtM.createAndShowGUI(artInMagazzino);
    }
```

This is the class PanelArticoliPerOrdine:

```
public class PanelArticoliPerOrdine extends abstractClass{
    static JDialog frame;
    public JTable table;
    public MyTableModelArticoliPerOrdine tableModel;
    JLabel picture;
    public List<Articoli> articoliMancanti;
    public Font fontTable;
    public PanelArticoliPerOrdine(List<Articoli> articoliMancanti) {
        this.setArticoliMancanti(articoliMancanti);
        fontTable = new Font("Century Gothic",Font.PLAIN, 16);
        
        tableModel = new MyTableModelArticoliPerOrdine();
        tableModel.stampaTabella(articoliMancanti);
        
        table = new JTable(tableModel);
        daiProprietaJTable();
        
        javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(table);
        jScrollPane1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (700,300));
        
        
        //Put the radio buttons in a column in a panel.
        JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel();
        radioPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Stampa Articoli"));
        GridBagConstraints GBC5 = new GridBagConstraints();
        Container CR5 = new Container();
        GridBagLayout GBL5 = new GridBagLayout();
        CR5.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.UNKNOWN);
        CR5.setLayout(GBL5);     
        radioPanel.add(CR5);

        GBC5 = new GridBagConstraints();
        CR5.add(jScrollPane1);
        GBC5.gridx=0;
        GBC5.gridy=0;
        GBC5.gridwidth=3;
        //    GBC5.gridheight=2;
        GBC5.insets.top=5;
        GBC5.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        GBL5.setConstraints(jScrollPane1,GBC5);



    
        add(radioPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
    }

    public void daiProprietaJTable(){
        table.setRowHeight(25);
        table.setFont(fontTable);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(560);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(70);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(70);
        DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer_archivi = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        renderer_archivi.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(renderer_archivi);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(renderer_archivi);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public static void createAndShowGUI(List<Articoli> vettoreArt) {
        frame = new JDialog();
        Dimensione d2 = new Dimensione();
        d2.setSize(800, 500);
        frame.setPreferredSize(d2);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        CentraComponents centra = new CentraComponents();
        Point coordinate = centra.centra(frame);
        frame.setLocation(coordinate);
        JComponent newContentPane = new PanelArticoliPerOrdine(vettoreArt);
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void chiudi(){
        frame.dispose();
    }

    

    public List<Articoli> getArticoliMancanti() {
        return articoliMancanti;
    }

    public void setArticoliMancanti(List<Articoli> articoliMancanti) {
        this.articoliMancanti = articoliMancanti;
    }

}
```

Now how can I change my code in order to return at the first method the articles selected by user showing using PanelArticoliPerOrdine class  ?

Comment: Did you look into table selection listeners and updating the reference the panel is using to display the article? Btw, `abstractClass` is as horrible a class name as can be - it doesn't say anything about the purpose of that class, it may be misleading readers (they might unintentionally read it as "abstract class") and it doesn't adhere to the Java coding conventions.

Comment: *"the user can select one of this and the method should to return the selected article"* - this is not how GUIs work.  Instead, you need to make use of an "observer pattern" that can be called when some kind of event occurs. I would suggest looking at [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html); [Selecting Items in a List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#selection); [Code Conventions for the Java](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-contents.html)